# Laravel ignores validation errors and makes form disappear

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-7

I have created a dynamic form to enter hiking gear items. At the beginning, all the user sees is a "select gear category" dropdown, and according to the gear category selected (for ex: "Shelters") -  another dropdown appears for the user to select the type of gear item (for ex: "tent"). Then as soon as the choice is made, the user gets a generic form for general features (like price, weight, brand, name etc) + a view partial that fetches (with axios) special features according to the type (if it's a tent - it'll get the N° of persons, if it's a backpack - the carry capacity, etc)

example of the form structure with the special features div:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                                        <select class="custom-select" name="manufacturer_id">
                                            <option value="" selected>Brand</option>
                                            @forelse ($manufacturers as $manufacturer)
                                            <option value="{{ $manufacturer->id }}"
                                                {{ (old("manufacturer_id") == $manufacturer->id ? "selected" : "") }}>
                                                {{ $manufacturer->name }}</option>
                                            @empty
                                            <option>No manufacturers</option>
                                            @endforelse
                                        </select>

                                        <small id="manufacturerHelp" class="form-text text-muted ">Not on our list? - <a
                                                href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manuf_modal">Add
                                                new</a>.</small>

                                        @error('manufacturer_id')
                                        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="container pt-3" v-show="formDisplay" id="itemType"
                                    style="background: #e1f7d5">
                                    <!-- This div displays the partial view related to the sub category chosen -->
                                </div>
```

so far so good. I managed to distribute the data into the appropriate tables via my controller. Here is my 'store' method:

```
public function store(){

        $data = request()->validate([

            'gear_categories_id' => 'required',
            'sub_categories_id' => 'required', 
            'name' => 'required', 
            'manufacturer_id' => 'required', 

        ]);


        $gearItem = auth()->user()->gearItem()->create($data);

        $featureModel = SpecialFeature::where('sub_categories_id', $gearItem->sub_categories_id)->value('model_name');

        $specialFeatures =  'App\\'.$featureModel;
        $featuresData['gear_items_id'] = $gearItem->id;
        $featureNames = SpecialFeature::where('sub_categories_id', $gearItem->sub_categories_id)->get();

        foreach ($featureNames as $featureName) {
            if (SpecialFeature::where('required', 0)->get()){
                $featuresData[$featureName->feature_name] = request($featureName->feature_name); 
            } else {
                $featuresData = request()->validate([
                    $featureName->feature_name => 'required'
                ]);
            }
        }

        $specialFeatures::create($featuresData);

        return redirect('/gearitem/'.$gearItem->id);

    }
```

The problem is, when I deliberately DO NOT fill in required fields in the form - instead of keeping the display of the form stable and displaying the message errors - the whole thing disappears, leaving only the the top drop down (gear categories) you have to re-select the category again - to see the errors.

And another thing - if there are required fields in the fetched "special features" div (id="itemType")- the errors won't even show when the user does not fill in the fields. the @error is completely ignored! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: It's properly indented in my IDE, when I copied it here it got all messy.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Laravel like Javascript, which wont work.

Laravel will only process on the server which means on form submission it redirects to the server via a route and on error is redirected back to a fresh loaded page.

So when it returns it goes back to the initial fresh loaded state, and because you are dynamically calling the form to the page the server has rendered and found no need to output errors.

So the issue is not that Laravel has removed your form and not output errors, its how you are trying to implement it with dynamic pages.

There are a few options to try do what you want:-

You could add some logic to the page to look for an extra variable on redirect back which remembers the state, loads the forms and populates it with data and errors.

Do an AJAX call to the route to validate and use a javascript promise to update the form on screen.

Use something like Livewire.

Comment: "You could add some logic to the page to look for an extra variable on redirect back which remembers the state, loads the forms and populates it with data and errors" - Ok, but what kind of logic? Is this some kind of a similar to "prevent default" command? How can I keep the form stable with errors appearing as long as the errors not corrected by the user?

Comment: For example submit the item_id with the form and return it with the errors, if the item_id is in the view payload then you know it has come from a form validation issue.  So instead of loading up the form via ajax, insert the form into the laravel blade and populate with data and errors.  Prevent default is a javascript command to stop the form being sent in the traditional way so you can replace it with an ajax call. A quick google search returned this https://codingdriver.com/laravel-form-submit-using-ajax-easy-example.html